# binary search on character array in java

Tags: java

I want to know how to do binary search on character array in java

There is a in-build function in java , but i don't want to use that , any help or pointers will be really appreciated.

I just started with below as i know binary search needs the array to be sorted

```
char[] whitelist = {'f','e','d','c','b','a'};

                Arrays.sort(whitelist);

                for (char ch : whitelist) {  
                    System.out.println("The values after sorting\n"+ch);
                }
```

Comment: I doubt that you really need help with google or [SO's search functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+binary+search).

Comment: If the array is sorted then you dont need to actually "search" it, if you want "f" then just count how far away f is from a and access the index of the whitelist at that position.

Comment: AntonioP I'm guessing he wants a system that will work even when he's not just spelling out the whole alphabet. :)

Answer (score 3):

As simple as Java does:

```
int binarySearch(char[] a, char key) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.length - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        char midVal = a[mid];

        if (midVal < key)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (midVal > key)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid; // key found
    }
    return -(low + 1);  // key not found.
}
```

Of course, replace the array `a` with your array, i.e. `whitelist`.

Basically, look out for this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Iterative

Comment: Especially for beginners it's good style to have properly indented code.

Comment: @kobe - No problems. This should work, since this is pretty much what is done by the in-built API as well. Generally, if you intend to implement an API on your own, it is good to see (in fact, leverage) the in-built API's **source** itself, to start with.

Comment: @Saket - this is **HOMEWORK**.  It is **bad form** to provide a potted answer that the OP can simply copy and paste ... as he is apparently doing.  The point of homework is to get the student to do the work, and learn in the process.  Giving him/her potted answers defeats the purpose.

Comment: (this is more or less copy/pasted from `Arrays#binarySearch0`)

Comment: @StephenC ,@andreas , I went through the logic and understood now , as you suggested i won't copy as it is.

Comment: @kobe you better not , because that strikingly similar to Java's built-in binary search , the one you were apparently told to avoid for the exercise .

Comment: @kobe - see the last line of my answer.